# Style not applying on select tag in react application

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am currently worrking on a react application but using a html bootstrap template, So the template already has the css styles and that what I'm using in my application. Everything was working fine until I noticed that the styles arent reflecting on all the select tags but other input fields are working just fine. I wanna know whats causing this, I tried reading up on react and select tags but nothing about why the css isnt reflecting, just articles on react-select. Which I would like to consider as a last option cause I would like to mantain the template styles.

[image: Screenshot of what other input field looks like and what the select tag looks like]

I would really like to know whats causing this and whats the best approach.

Comment: See MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select which states that select is notoriously difficult to style. That article has a couple of references but you may end up having to implement your own select substitute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to read the docs [here](https://react-select.com/styles)  about custom styling,
Also you can try creating your own css class and add it to the tag, but you should add `!important` after each property like that

```
.example{ color:"purple" !important; }
```

Comment: Thanks mate, didnt follow it exactly. What I did was inspect the rendered html tag, get the classname, added that to my css file with the styles I wanted and the !important  to override the previous styles